# virtual machine stuck

Tags: kali-linux, error-handling, download

[image]

My virtual machine stuck on this and just keep downloadin for hours please solve

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What VM? What is the host OS? What is the guest? Presumably Kali? You might also want to consider not using Kali. It is not a general purpose operating system and requires significant expertise. See https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to the second *virtual console*. If your keyboard has two Ctrl keys, use the *right Ctrl* key instead of the left one.

You should see a root prompt on a text-based display.
Use it to find out what is going on:

- verify network connectivity with `ip link show` and `ip addr show`
- verify there is free disk space with `df -h`
- use `ps axf` to view the process tree, and locate the process responsible for installing the `php8.2` package. If it is hung, kill it, and remember that this will leave the installation of that package incomplete, and so you will need to reinstall that package manually later.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to return to the installer.

If the root prompt on the second virtual console is also unresponsive, the VM has hung; turn it off and on again, and retry the installation.